# Improve wording on no-review edit 'approvals'

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

Apparently I'm ["trusted to make this change without review"](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/18154)

[image]

Without going into how much incredibly poor judgment is required to trust me on anything, the wording seems awkward. Instead of "Approved by" with no reviewers, make it just say "Approved":

[image]

Comment: "how much incredibly poor judgment is required to trust me on anything" exactly my point! Your face is too cute to be true!

Comment: Also, what is the level where you are pre-approved? Is it a moderator privilege? 15k rep? "Trusted User" is 20k and Undo isn't there yet...

Comment: @TylerH Hard to tell; diamonds grant all privileges across the board regardless of reputation.

Comment: @Undo Hmm, that's true, but you can also use some parts of the site as a non-moderator. For example moderators can still Mjolnir dupes like regular users, and go through the review queues like regular users, too.

Comment: Not really @TylerH - Mjolnir happens to show up, but it'd be a unilateral close with or without it. Going through the review queues is scary because everything you do is unilateral there.

Comment: @Undo You mean you aren't able to do a moderator close of a dupe in a question tagged with something you're a gold badge in, *without* the Mjolnir banner showing up? Also I seem to recall Jon or someone explicitly saying they were going through the review queues as a normal user... maybe I just misunderstood them though

Comment: Right, @TylerH.

Comment: @TylerH Interesting bit here: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/19993 didn't immediately go through, so there might be some subject/tag score requirement.

Comment: @Undo What change did you make there? I can't see any

Comment: @TylerH Added a version, which [apparently disables the moderator bypass](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/31844026#31844026). Also see http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/31843947#31843947 for definitive explanation of how 'trusted' works (spoiler: it means 'moderator' right now).

Comment: @Undo Gotcha. Thanks... at least Kevin and the team are aware of it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The review UI sort of side-stepped this altogether, but we still have the old views around, so I made the change to fix it just in case we go back to them or surface them in another way down the road.